# GQL query with Google Cloud Datasore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

[Google Datastore Runquery](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery) provides http client to perform GQL query as like below:

```
POST https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id:runQuery?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "gqlQuery": {
  "queryString": "SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = 'user@example.com'"
 }
}
```

But I am getting error response like:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Disallowed literal: 'user@example.com'.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

But, `Google Cloud Datastore Http Client` work perfectly with simple query like `'Select * from User'`.

So, How can this GQL Query be executed with Datastore Http client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the allowLiterals parameter to true or use bindings for the parameters (either named or positional).

See the documentation below:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery#GqlQuery

So if you want to allow literals (constant values) in the query, you should change the request to

```
{
 "gqlQuery": {
  "queryString": "SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = 'user@example.com'"
  "allowLiterals": true
 }
}
```